# how to animate the imageviews when other imageviews are visible to the user?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, imageview

I have five imageview's in my layout.first 3 are visible, 4th and 5th are gone at first time. After some time 4th imageview is visible at that time of visibility first 3 imageviews are scale down and 4th imageview is visible to the user same way 5th imageview visibile.what is the possible animation for imageview scale and card visibility?below is my layout

```
                   <RelativeLayout

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:visibility="visible">
                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/image_1"
                                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                                        android:layout_height="85dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"/>

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/image_2"
                                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                                        android:layout_height="85dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"                                             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_1"/>                                                                         

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/image_3"
                                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                                        android:layout_height="85dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_2"/>

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/image_4"
                                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_3"
                                    android:visibility="gone"/>



                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image_5"
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="85dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_4"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: make a method and pass the id of imageView that you don't want to animate. Inside that method apply animation on each imageView who's id is different than the id that you passed in that method.

Answer (score 0):

in your parent relative layout add the following line  `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` and it will automatically animate the visibility/gone of all image views

```
               <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                       android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/image_1"
                                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"/>

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/image_2"
                                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"                                             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_1"/>                                                                         

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/image_3"
                                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_2"/>

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image_4"
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="85dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_3"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>



                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image_5"
                            android:layout_width="65dp"
                            android:layout_height="85dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/empty_card"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_4"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
```